# what is the name of my form,mvc3 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I appreciate very much your help with the next:

Actually I'm working with mvc3 (razor) and vb.net ,

```
in my view:

@Using Html.BeginForm()
my content ....
End Using
```

when I see my view from browsers

```
<form action="/App/Schedule/Capt" method="post">    <fieldset>
```

and I want to get the name of this form.
**what is the name of my form??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify some properties in htmlAttributes parameter. Try something like this:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, New With {.name = "formName", .Id = "formId" })

   my content ....

End Using
```

By default, [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) does not generate a name for `<form />` tag. So, using htmlAttributes anyoimous type you can set the name, id, enctype, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The form element does not have a name.

As you can see, there is no `id` or `name` attribute on the element. And it normally doesn't need one.

You can pass in an optional ID to the `BeginForm` HTML Helper, however.

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", New With {.Id = "TheId"})
```